# Randomly re-assign 1's to 0's to reach a specified ratio

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array

```
my_array = np.array([1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0])
```

In this array, 50% of the items are 1's.  I want to efficiently and randomly switch some of the 1's to 0's so that the ratio is 20%.

```
new_array = switch_function(my_array)
print new_array 

array([0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]) #random switching retaining order
```

This seems like it should be simple and everything I thought of seems over-engineered.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: what have you thought of? because wanting something to be both `efficient and random` seems to be a oxymoron

Comment: what is `my_array.dtype`? Is it always sorted? Set 20% to `1`, shuffle.

Comment: dtype is int, only 0's and 1's, not sorted (modified example to clear confusion)

Comment: Random is a requirement for statistical reasons.  Efficient as possible given the constraint of random.

Comment: do you want all the original 0's to be in the same place?

Comment: original zeros must remain.  I don't want to re-sort, only change should be that some of the 1's change to 0's (good question)

Comment: best way to do is would probably be to iterate through each element and do something like `if x[i] == 1: x[i] = random.randint(0,1)` then nest that all inside of a while loop that checks percentage of 1's. this can end up giving you a percentage less than 20 so you might want to instead make your `randint(1,2)` and then later replace all your 2's with 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, something like this should work:

```
>>> arr = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1])
>>> want_frac = 0.2
>>> n = int(round(arr.sum() - want_frac * len(arr)))
>>> indices_to_flip = np.random.choice(arr.nonzero()[0], n, replace=False)
>>> arr[indices_to_flip] = 0
>>> arr
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
>>> arr.mean()
0.20000000000000001
```

First we figure out how many numbers we need to flip (trying our best to get close to the right value) then we randomly choose `n` of the nonzero indices, and finally we set them to zero.

Note that as JFS notes in comments, you should verify that `n > 0`, to make sure you don't accidentally make changes you don't intend.

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I think it's okay, actually; if `n <= 0`, `indices_to_flip` is empty and the assignment simply does nothing, which since it's already optimal is what we want.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't get empty indices list with `n<0` ( `np.__version__ == '1.8.2'`)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: oh, wow.  I get empty indices with n=0,-2,-3,-4,... etc, but not -1!  I stand corrected.  (I tried 0 and then -2 and -3 in my tests..)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to accomplish this kind of task. Here is a simple approach.

```
# Get the array length
N = len(my_array)

# Proportion of 1's
p = np.sum(my_array) / float(N)

# Locations of 1's
idx = np.arange(0, N)[my_array == 1]

# Calculate how many idx to change
k = (p*N) - (0.2 * N)

# Sample the idx and change values to 0
my_array[np.random.choice(idx, int(k), False)] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to keep the existing zeros as zeros, and simply want the entire array to have an average of 20% 1's, could you not go through your array with a "for" loop, and for each element call randint(1,5). If randint returns 1, set your array item to 1, else set it to zero.

If however you wish to retain all the original zeros, that means you want to reduce the number of 1's to 40% of the number there now, so go through the array, if the number is 1,call randint(1,5) and if it returns 1 or 2, retain the original 1, else change it to zero.